# npm pulling old, insecure modules and not updating them

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get a modern version of some dependencies for a node.js app installed on Windows with cygwin.  There are a few others, but I will just show mongodb as an example.  It looks like mongodb 3.1.12 is available, but the one installed is stuck at 1.4.12.  `npm audit fix` and even `--force` don't seem to update anything.  None of this should be global, so all used modules are in an app-local node_modules directory.  I noticed there is no `.npmrc` either globally, in the app folder or in ~, but it seems npm is going to a repository with modern versions.

[EDIT] adding app's package.json.  Mine has the carrets:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node -v",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-sessions": "^1.0.1",
    "latest-version": "^6.0.0",
    "mssql": "^5.1.5",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "reinstall": "^2.0.0",
    "tedious": "^4.0.4"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?
TIA.

````
$ npm -v
7.22.0

$ ls -la
total 6481
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Sep  3 10:22 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Sep  3 10:22 ..
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Aug  9 13:11 creds
-rw-rwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users 6410670 Sep  2 11:38 modules.tgz
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Sep  3 10:00 node_modules
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Aug 18 10:19 output_files
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users  120133 Sep  3 10:54 package-lock.json
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users     424 Sep  3 10:00 package.json
drwxrwxr-x+ 1 K143794 Domain Users       0 Sep  3 07:36 www

$ npm audit
# npm audit report
. . .
mongodb  <=3.1.12
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1203
Depends on vulnerable versions of bson
Depends on vulnerable versions of kerberos
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/mongodb
  mongoose  0.0.3 - 0.0.6 || 1.7.2 - 5.11.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mongodb
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mpath
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mquery
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ms
  node_modules/mongoose
. . .
12 vulnerabilities (1 low, 7 moderate, 4 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

$ npm list mongodb
server@1.0.0 C:\dev\automation\Server
└─┬ express-sessions@1.0.1
  └─┬ mongoose@3.9.7
    └── mongodb@1.4.12


$ npm audit fix

up to date, audited 194 packages in 3s
. . .
mongodb  <=3.1.12
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1203
Depends on vulnerable versions of bson
Depends on vulnerable versions of kerberos
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/mongodb
  mongoose  0.0.3 - 0.0.6 || 1.7.2 - 5.11.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mongodb
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mpath
  Depends on vulnerable versions of mquery
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ms
  node_modules/mongoose
. . .
12 vulnerabilities (1 low, 7 moderate, 4 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

$ npm list mongodb
server@1.0.0 C:\dev\automation\Server
└─┬ express-sessions@1.0.1
  └─┬ mongoose@3.9.7
    └── mongodb@1.4.12


$ cat node_modules/mongodb/package.json
{ "name" :            "mongodb"
, "description" :     "A node.js driver for MongoDB"
, "keywords" :        ["mongodb", "mongo", "driver", "db"]
, "version" :         "1.4.12"
, "repository" :    { "type" :  "git"
                    , "url" :   "http://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native.git" }
, "bugs" :          { "mail" :  "node-mongodb-native@googlegroups.com"
                    , "url" :   "http://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues" }
, "dependencies" : {
  "bson": "~0.2"
}
, "devDependencies": {
      "dox": "0.4.4"
    , "uglify-js": "1.2.5"
    , "ejs": "0.6.1"
    , "request": "2.12.0"
    , "nodeunit": "0.7.3"
          , "markdown": "0.3.1"
          , "gleak": "0.2.3"
          , "step": "0.0.5"
          , "async": "0.1.22"
    , "integra": "0.0.3"
    , "optimist": "latest"
  }
, "optionalDependencies": {
      "kerberos": "0.0.4"
    , "readable-stream": "latest"
  }
, "config":         { "native" : false }
, "main":             "./lib/mongodb/index"
, "homepage":         "http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/"
, "directories" :   { "lib" : "./lib/mongodb" }
, "engines" :       { "node" : ">=0.6.19" }
, "scripts": { "test" : "make test_functional" }
, "licenses" :    [ { "type" :  "Apache License, Version 2.0"
                    , "url" :   "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0" } ]
}```
````

Comment: Your package.json has actual version numbers for the dependencies, you need to add ^ in front of the first number. Then delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json and reinstall them.

Comment: That was the mongodb's package.json.  Mine has the ^ in there; added it above.